# How can I get my web controls to display over an activex control?

Tags: html, activex, z-index

I'm not sure if this is completely possible.  I am designing a website that displays some activex reports.  I have suggested that the use of activex be discontinued and another reporting tool/technology be used, but for now we're sticking with it.

I have found that graphical Activex objects display in Windowed mode, and other page objects display in Windowless mode.  Windowed objects always display on top of windowless objects, regardless of Z-index.

Because of this, the drop downs that I am placing, and a drop down login screen, are all obscured when this particular report is displayed.

I need a way to render the Drop-downs on top of the activex control, and I have been unable to discover a reliable way to do this.

I feel like I should be able to somehow do this using an iframe, but I haven't found any working examples.

How can I get the drop downs other website elements to display in front/over the activex control?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer, and the solution i used, was to stop using activex, or just use a plain select box, which will render over the control.

Any of the nice CSS/Jquery select boxes ([select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/)) will not display over activex...